# Wordpress Notice: Constant FS_CHMOD_DIR already defined in Wp-Cofig

Tags: wordpress, chmod

All of sudden after updating to Wordpress I am getting the following error:

```
Notice: Constant FS_CHMOD_DIR already defined in /home/mink7/public_html/sites/anandmenon.in/wp-config.php on line 101

Notice: Constant FS_CHMOD_FILE already defined in /home/mink7/public_html/sites/anandmenon.in/wp-config.php on line 101
```

http://anandmenon.in/

Comment: Do you use Comet Cache?

Comment: Its Cpanel so dont think so

Comment: sure will do that :)

Comment: Here is your answer, check your file permissions.https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253274/use-of-undefined-constant-fs-chmod-dir-assumed-fs-chmod-dir

Comment: Did you checked your wp-config.php. There is purpose override the default permission ? Or else first remove defined constant FS_CHMOD_DIR  and FS_CHMOD_FILE from wp-config.php